# React Zustand confirm dialog return value

Tags: reactjs, zustand

Just got started with Zustand. Trying to implement a confirm dialog. It is working but i can't get the last bit. I am trying to get a return value if the user declined the dialog, however i am lacking the understanding.

This is what i got so far.
Calling the confirm Dialog:

```
confirmDialog("Are you sure?", (userAccepted) => {                  
              replace(userAccepted)
            })
// I am not able to run code if a user declines the dialog. confirmDialog yields void
function replace(userAccepted: boolean) {
 ...
 }
```

I am struggeling with running code when a user declines the dialog.

This is my store:

```
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogActions, Button, Box, IconButton, Alert } from "@pankod/refine-mui"

import create from "zustand"

type ConfirmDialogStore = {
   message: string
   onSubmit?: (userAccepted: boolean) => void
   close: () => void
}

const useConfirmDialogStore = create<ConfirmDialogStore>((set) => ({
   //states and their default values
   message: "",
   onSubmit: undefined,
   // Updating state via close property (which is a function)
   close: () => set({ onSubmit: undefined }),
}))

export const confirmDialog = (message: string, onSubmit: (userAccepted: boolean) => void) => {
   // Schreibt in den Store
   useConfirmDialogStore.setState({
      message,
      onSubmit,
   })
}

const ConfirmDialog = () => {
   // Liest aus dem Store
   const { message, onSubmit, close } = useConfirmDialogStore()

   // This will be rendered if Boolean(onSubmit) is true / if onSubmit is provided
   return (
      <Dialog
         open={Boolean(onSubmit)}
         onClose={close}
         maxWidth="sm"
         fullWidth
      >
         <Box
            display="flex"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            alignItems="center"
         >
            <DialogTitle>Bist du Sicher?</DialogTitle>
            <IconButton onClick={close}>{/* <Close /> */}</IconButton>
         </Box>
         <DialogContent>
            <Alert severity="error">{message}</Alert>
         </DialogContent>
         <DialogActions sx={{ padding: (theme) => theme.spacing(2) }}>
            <Button
               color="primary"
               variant="contained"
               onClick={close}
            >
               Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button
               color="secondary"
               variant="contained"
               onClick={() => {
                  if (onSubmit) {
                     onSubmit(true)
                  }
                  close()
               }}
            >
               Confirm
            </Button>
         </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
   )
}

export default ConfirmDialog
```